# g++ hangs when compile

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a bit of code that I can compile fine with g++. Then I make some arrays larger:

```
complex<double> densop[a][b][c]
```

Where a=b=400, g=500. And when I compile with

```
g++ -L/.../gsl  -I/../gsl -O2 -lgsl -lgslcblas  -Wall -o sim1 sim1.cp
```

The compiler hangs (5h+) with no extra warning than in the case where it compiles.

I thought it could have been the memory but top shows CPU running at 100% and %MEM about half. Btw I also declared the array globally so that it wouldnt be heavy on the stack.

Another thing that varies between case that compiles ok and not is when I #include two data files where in the second case are bigger (30 and 15 MB).

gcc version 4.1.2, Memory 30GB. Tried with both -O0 and -O2 flags.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show more code around the variable declaration.  For example, is it declared in a function or at file scope or as a static?

Comment: Just as a note, that array as written is `80000000` elements of `double`, which is a total size of `640 MB`. With the specs you listed, that shouldn't be an issue, but thought I'd include that detail in case it jumped out at anyone.

Comment: @Cyber The element type is `complex<double>`, which is effectively the size of two doubles. So the total memory use is 1280MB.

Comment: Yeah, that memory should probably be allocated dynamically otherwise you are going to have one hell of an executable size...

Comment: Unfortunately the machine is shared, I don't have permission to update g++ and bit short with time!

Comment: Also I saw those threads about the gcc bug but they all referred to newer versions

Comment: the variable declaration was global, used only in a void function. I am trying now to see what happens if I declare it in the function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have certainly seen cases where g++ has poor performance when parsing large constant data arrays as C++ source code. One way to improve this is to store the large data array(s) in input file(s), and load them into memory at program startup. This will fix the compile performance problem at the cost of a small amount of startup processing at runtime.

Note that even if your constant arrays compile and run, they'll still need to call the `complex<double>` constructor a few million times, so reading from a file probably won't cost much.

Comment: *"they'll still need to call the complex<double> constructor a few million times"* At `-O2`? Sure? `complex<T>` are literal types, and their ctors are `constexpr`.

Comment: Well, maybe not, depending on the compiler implementation. I wouldn't necessarily trust a g++ 4.1 to do such a thing.

Comment: I am a bit confused, the array doesn't get populated but at run time. Do you mean to save the array in a separate text file?

Comment: @user3744868: Perhaps I'm confused; you said "when I #include two data files" - what is in those data files? I was assuming you were including big constant data files.

Comment: Those data files contain text. They are imported with #include and some variables (10 approx) are replaced. Then they are used in a different function from where the array is processed. What do you mean with "load them into memory at program startup."