# Disable compiler optimization with GCC 5.4.0 and RelWithDebInfo build type

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, compiler-optimization

When building [this project](https://github.com/AprilRobotics/apriltags) in `RelWithDebInfo` build type, the compilation takes so much time that I just abort the process.

There are some big source code ([e.g.](https://github.com/AprilRobotics/apriltags/blob/026985020255134b66acf4ff3f0dc87971e29b52/tagCircle49h12.c)) and `__attribute__((optimize("O0")))` is used to disable the compiler optimization with GCC.

While this works in `Debug` or `Release` mode, this seems to not work in `RelWithDebInfo` build mode.

Tested environment is `Ubuntu 16.04` and `GCC 5.4.0`.

Is there a workaround to avoid this issue other than upgrade to a newer GCC version? Is this a compiler bug?

To reproduce the issue on `Ubuntu 16.04` with `GCC 5.4.0`, something like:

```
git clone https://github.com/AprilRobotics/apriltags.git
git checkout 0269850
cd apriltags
mkdir build
cd build
ccmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
make -j4 //this takes too much time with GCC 5.4.0
```

Comment: Why not just let it finish compiling?

Comment: I gotta say, I was horrified when I saw `tagCircle49h12.c`. Why would *anyone* put more than 65,000 lines of code in a file, when all that code was doing was manually filling an array with data? That's a *terrible* way to incorporate a large amount of raw data into a program. **Absolutely terrible.**

Burn this project to the ground.

Comment: Possibly related? [GCC compilation very slow (large file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443626/gcc-compilation-very-slow-large-file) and [g++ hangs when compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899277/g-hangs-when-compile)